# For technical vocabulary questions, what site should I use?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, specific-question, asking-questions

I am not trying to do something technical.  I just want to understand a couple of things about SaltStack.  Which site is the most appropriate for vocabulary questions?

Here are the technical DevOps questions (about the configuration management tool SaltStack) that I want to ask:

What is a highdata structure in SaltStack?  (As seen [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/highstate.html).)

What is an SLS name in SaltStack?  (In the context of "state.apply invoked with SLS names will run state.sls".)

Comment: For entry-level questions about any technology, or terminology in general, I'd recommend [Google over StackExchange](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/highstate.html).  It's faster and more definitive, and there's not much more a quality answerer can do than recite the documentation. Not sure you'd get any particular value from asking these questions on SE.

Comment: I agree with @DanBron If you then cannot find answers you will be in a better position to say where you've looked, what you've found and where you are stuck in a more detailed question on perhaps [su].

Comment: potentially of interest: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops?referrer=cZS_mCq3NdL7h376hrOevQ2